# Objects inside Array, how to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, object, arr

> My question is, how can i access each object inside an Array? or
>   perhaps, how am I supposed to solve this problem? Like I know in head,
>   i have to compare categories and then push into new const array that
>   category. So far, i get each object in array wrote down, but I need to
>   do an push method after category is same, and also after that to
>   splice the category from each object.
>
> My solution so far:

```
export const convert = inside => {
inside(({id,name,category}) => {
outside[category].push({id,name});
});
console.log(outside);
return outside;
}
```

Sorry for messed code, could not load here.

Comment: Is your desired logic to check if an item in the `inside` list exists in the `outside` list? or is it to get both `fruit` & `vegetable` lists and combine them into one list with their respective `category`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the `category` as key for the object and push a new object.

No need for an array for every category, because this appoach uses the result object with dynamic keys.

```js
const
    inside = [{ id: 1, name: "orange", category: "fruits" }, { id: 2, name: "apple", category: "fruits" }, { id: 3, name: "carrot", category: "vegetable" }],
    outside = {};
    
inside.forEach(({ id, name, category }) => {
    outside[category] = outside[category] || [];
    outside[category].push({ id, name });
});

console.log(outside);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Only thing i don't get, is this line `outside[category] = outside[category] || [];`,
can you please explain it? 

I am learning Javascript etc. for 1 week +- ... So i am not any pro, mostly learned css and html from start... And im using codeCademy.

Comment: tjis is a powerful pattern, because if you have the property **in** the object and if the value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like an array (please have a look to the links!), then it assigns this value, because [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) stops here to evaluate the next operand. in short, if you have an array, take it.

Comment: the second part comes into consideration, if the first part, in this case the property does not exists or have a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, this falsy value forces to take the second part (the empty array).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure i understand the question but from what i think is needed, you want to take all the items from the `outside` constant and take their respective `category`, apply it to the food Object and then add that Object to the `inside` variable.

```js
const outside = {
  fruits: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "orange"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "apple"
  }],
  vegetable: [{
    id: 3,
    name: "carrot"
  }]
}
const categories = Object.keys(outside)

let inside = []

categories.forEach(category => {
  const categorizedFood = outside[category].map(f => ({...f, category }) )
  
  inside = [...inside, ...categorizedFood]
})

console.log(inside)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  background: #FFF; 
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(210deg);
}
```